# Is there any way to remove ads?

Tags: temple-run-2

> **Note:** For the sake of accessibility, please provide an answer for all platforms; Windows Phone, iOS and Android where possible.
>   For my case, I'm using iOS and Android.

---

So, in many [free-to-play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-to-play) video games, there are many methods of which companies try to make money off you (open to speculation, but please do not discuss it here). One of the ways, is by placing advertisements in their games.

However, some allow the option to pay for the removal of such ads, such as in Piano Tiles, which comes in the form of a restorable microtransation in the options menu.
However, in Temple Run 2, I do not see such option.

**Question:** Is there such microtransation in Temple Run 2 that can remove advertising? (ie. Purchase a gem/coin pack) or is the only way to remove advertisements is to brutefore (ie. use an ad-blocker or proxy-block all advertisement sources)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to pay to remove ads or the option to do so isn't available, a more elegant solution then bruteforce or blocking the ads sources is to disable your Wi-Fi and cellular data, because the app is unable to access the internet it will not display ads.

> Note that this option will not work for games that require an internet connection

Comment: I will accept if nobody can come up with a paid option.

Comment: I highly doubt there will be if there is no way to do so within the app, but we will see

Comment: Also, I think you're guessing. Do you have verification to back this up?

Comment: It's what I've done many times before and it works